# Inexpensive PPTP appliance

Tags: networking, vpn, pptp

I'm looking for an inexpensive VPN appliance that supports PPTP. I've found a few that do IPSec, but I want to be able to use the built-in PPTP client in Windows. I know I can use Windows Server or Linux for this, but I don't want to use a full blown PC or server for this.

What products are out there that fit into a shoestring budget?

Answer (score 4):

We use [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org/) and [m0nowall](http://m0n0.ch/wall/) for this - simple to use web-based admin.  You can use an old PC with a [Disk on Module](http://www.pqimemory.com/products-storage.asp) in the IDE connector or a single-board-computer like ALIX from [pcengines](http://www.pcengines.ch/).  Found this solution to be cheap and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

The DD-WRT firmware can turn an inexpensive router into a PPTP server
http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/PPTP_Server_Configuration

Answer (score 0):

The Draytek routers are inexpensive and support PPTP.  [www.draytek.com](http://www.draytek.com)

Answer (score 0):

I use a Cisco/Linksys RV042 router.  It has a built in PPTP server option.